# How can i set a DateTime value in a new constructor?

Tags: c#

I am creating a new customer from my constructor in my customer class and i cannot get the new customer to accept a DateTime value in my main method. I have tried multiple formats for entry and none have worked. How can i get the new customer to accept a DateTime imput.

Here is my customer class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;



    class Customer
    {

        //Strings

        private string _LastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _LastName; }
            set { _LastName = value; }
        }
        private string _FirstName;
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _FirstName; }
            set { _FirstName = value; }
        }
        private string _Address;
        public string Address
        {
            get { return _Address; }
            set { _Address = value; }
        }
        private Int32 _ContactNumber;
        public Int32 ContactNumber
        {
            get { return _ContactNumber; }
            set { _ContactNumber = value; }
        }
        private string _EmailAddress;
        public string EmailAddress
        {
            get { return _EmailAddress; }
            set { _EmailAddress = value; }
        }
        private DateTime _Dob;
        public DateTime Dob
        {
            get { return _Dob; }
            set { _Dob = value; }
        }

        //Accounts
        private List<Account> _Accounts = new List<Account>();
        public ReadOnlyCollection<Account> Accounts
        {
            get { return _Accounts.AsReadOnly(); }
        }

        //Adding Accounts
        public void AddAccount(Account account)
        {
            _Accounts.Add(account);
        }

        // Constructor
        public Customer(string LastName, string FirstName, string Address, int ContactNumber, string EmailAddress, DateTime Dob)
        {
            _LastName = LastName;
            _FirstName = FirstName;
            _Address = Address;
            _ContactNumber = ContactNumber;
            _EmailAddress = EmailAddress;
            _Dob = Dob;
        }



    }
```

Here is my main method:

```
using System;

    class MainMethod
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            Customer Arley = new Customer("Praise", "Arley", "12 Hay Rd", 0412232116, "arleyp@gmail.com", DateTime(02,10,1990));


        }
    }
```

For further clarification i am referring to my main method and having an error in the new customer, specifically "DateTime(02,10,1990)"

Comment: Use `Year, Month, Day` instead of `Day, Month, Year`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using "new DateTime(1900,02,10)"

the format is year, month, day.. You also need to use the word new to make a new DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the new keyword and fix the property order:

```
new DateTime(1990, 2, 10)
```

Comment: 1990 is a valid year, 2 is a valid month or day, 10 is also a valid month or day, so that would give you 10th Feb 1990 - that looks pretty valid

Comment: I fixed the order after Lithium pointed out that what I copied from OP's code snippet was wrong.

Comment: @BugFinder That was before the edit he kept the wrong order, it has since been fixed.

Comment: @Lithium I do not see any issue. `2` or `10` both can be `Month` or a `Day`.

Comment: Fair enough @Lithium